# Cumulative sum after 64 in Python(Conditional Cumulative sum)

Tags: python, r, cumulative-sum

I am new to python. I am not sure how to do the following function in python. I am able to do this in R. But not able to do it in python. Can anybody help me in this?

I want to get the cumulative sum of the counter value once it reaches 64,

The following is my data,

```
x = [57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 58, 61, 61, 62, 62, 1, 1, 11, 16, 
     16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 22, 22, 22, 27, 28]
```

I want the cumulative sum after the count reaches 64. I am not sure how to do that in python.

The following is the output I require,

```
x = [57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 58, 61, 61, 62, 62, 65, 65, 75, 80, 
     80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 86, 86, 86, 91, 92]
```

This is basically a counter, so there would be many number of resets. The
following is the R code which I used,

```
x1<-cumsum(c(0,diff(sub$x)<0))
  sub$x<-sub$x+64*x1
```

Can anybody help me with doing this in Python?

Comment: Are you using any particular Python libraries (e.g. NumPy)?

Comment: I am using NumPy in my program. But not sure how to do this function in NumPy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`np.ediff1d(x, to_begin=[0]) < 0`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html) in NumPy is equivalent to `c(0,diff(sub$x)<0)` in R.
It takes the difference between consecutive elements and pads the result with a zero on the left. The rest is pretty much a 1-to-1 correspondence:

```
In [125]: x
Out[125]: 
array([ 57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  58.,  58.,  58.,  58.,  61.,
        61.,  62.,  62.,   1.,   1.,  11.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,
        16.,  22.,  22.,  22.,  27.,  28.])

In [126]: (np.ediff1d(x, to_begin=[0])<0).cumsum()*64 + x
Out[126]: 
array([ 57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  57.,  58.,  58.,  58.,  58.,  61.,
        61.,  62.,  62.,  65.,  65.,  75.,  80.,  80.,  80.,  80.,  80.,
        80.,  86.,  86.,  86.,  91.,  92.])
```

Comment: This code doesn't work well when the first value is around 200. It works well when it starts with 0. Is there a way we can change the code?

Comment: If `x[0] = 200`, the code above, `(np.ediff1d(x, to_begin=[0])<0).cumsum()*64 + x` returns `array([ 200.,  121.,  121.,  121.,..., 156.])`. I believe that is the same result returned by the `R` code you posted. What do you mean by "doesn't work well"?

Comment: for example, (239 , 47,47, ....48...50)

My output should be 239, 286,...,289,290...

Comment: If my data starts with 0, your code is correct. But when it starts with 200 something, I want it to continue from 200 and carry on with the sum, and again when it value reaches to 0, my count should still carry on

Comment: Suppose, the values are (82,82,25,25,26,26)

the difference is (0,0,-57,0,0,1,1) and then when we change to cumsum it becomes 0,0,1,1,1,1 and then it become (0,0,64,64,64) and then it gets added to the current value.

When the values are (239,47,47,48,48),

difference is 0,-192,0,0,1,1

then too values become 0,1,1,1, and then become 0,64,64

I want it to become ( 0,3,3,3,3,3) and then become 0, 192,192.. then get added to the current value and after that when the normal values come, it should manage by 0,1,1... can you give me an idea how to do that?

Comment: haimen, this is not the same problem as what you first posted. I'm still confused what the complete set of rules are that govern this new computation. **Please start a new question** which spells out everything completely and unambiguously. If you can implement it in R that would be very helpful.